# Undecidable or Decidable

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

In a typical data structures class, we look at a variety of problems: finding an element in a list,
sorting a list, balancing a binary search tree, finding the shortest paths in a graph, etc.
Would these problems be decidable or undecidable?

Wouldn't the answer to this question be both, because decidable means a clear yes/no answer and undecidable would mean that there is no clear answer to the question.

Comment: Decidable means “can be solved by a Turing machine”.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an algorithm, it is decidable. Its impossible for something to be not decidable and decidable at the same time. Take a look at the formal definition of a decidable language.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those problems are decidable.  Many of them are neither decidable nor undecidable.

Some problems are [decision problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem); some are not.  If you have a decision problem, you can ask whether it is decidable or not.  Most decision problems that you'll see in a data structures class will have an algorithm that terminates in a finite amount of time, so they'll be decidable.  For other kinds of problems (not a decision problem), you can't ask whether they are decidable; the notion of "decidable" isn't even defined.  There is a related notion of [computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability) which is broader than decidability.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability#Problems.